# DocuSign API: SignHere and InitialHere tabs getting inserted multiple times in envelope when using composite templates

Tags: docusignapi

I recently changed my DocuSign envelope sending implementation to start using composite templates instead of direct documents and noticed that all anchors in the documents are getting multiple signing tabs inserted therefore causing every anchor to have to be signed N (amount of composite templates in envelope) number of times by the customer. For example in the document you can see that it is requiring two initials to occur instead of just one like it used to before using composites:

[image]

I have confirmed that the documents I'm sending do not have duplicate anchor text so it seems there's either an issue with the request I'm sending (which is created from the C# DocuSign library) or a configuration issue with our DocuSign account. Here's is the JSON request for the above example:

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "[redacted]",
        "documentId": "1",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "Job Directions",
        "transformPdfFields": "False"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "customer@mail.com",
                "emailNotification": {
                  "emailBody": "[redacted]",
                  "emailSubject": "Map and Directions"
                },
                "name": "Abraham Lincoln",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "dateSignedTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "#signerdate1#"
                    }
                  ],
                  "initialHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "#initial1#"
                    }
                  ],
                  "listTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "#paymentmethod#",
                      "listItems": [
                        {
                          "text": "Cash"
                        },
                        {
                          "text": "Check"
                        },
                        {
                          "text": "Wire"
                        }
                      ],
                      "required": "true",
                      "tabLabel": "Payment Method",
                      "width": "200"
                    }
                  ],
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "#signer1#"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "[redacted]",
        "documentId": "2",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "Job Map",
        "transformPdfFields": "False"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "customer@mail.com",
                "emailNotification": {
                  "emailBody": "[redacted]",
                  "emailSubject": "Map and Directions"
                },
                "name": "Abraham Lincoln",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "dateSignedTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "#signerdate1#"
                    }
                  ],
                  "initialHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "#initial1#"
                    }
                  ],
                  "listTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "#paymentmethod#",
                      "listItems": [
                        {
                          "text": "Cash"
                        },
                        {
                          "text": "Check"
                        },
                        {
                          "text": "Wire"
                        }
                      ],
                      "required": "true",
                      "tabLabel": "Payment Method",
                      "width": "200"
                    }
                  ],
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "#signer1#"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Map and Directions",
  "enforceSignerVisibility": "true",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

We've been in contact with a support person at DocuSign for days but they don't know what is even happening. They've tried setting our Anchor Population Scope to "Document" but when they did that we started getting this error "ONESIGNALLSIGN_NOT_SATISFIED" returned in the DocuSign response.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to what may be happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your anchor strings scope is set to envelope (vs. document) then DocuSign will scan all documents in the envelope (regardless of how they got into the envelope) for these strings.

You clearly specify the same anchor string twice for both your inline templates expecting it will only apply for the documents in that template, but that's not how it works. It applies to the entire envelope.

To maintain flexibility you can just change the anchor strings from one template to the other to be something different, but if you need them to be the same - specify them only in one of the two templates.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for the quick response. Just adding the recipients to one of the inline templates worked. I thought I had to add the recipients for each composite template since I was thinking those recipients would only apply to the specified document.